# If my counter ends at 10 at textbox1(TB1) the random number won't show in my textbox2(TB2)

Tags: vb.net, timer

If my counter ends at 10 at textbox1 (TB1) the random number won't show in my textbox2(TB2)

[image]

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If TB1.Text = 10 Then
            Dim num1 As Integer
            Dim randomnumber As New Random

            num1 = randomnumber.Next(100, 201)
            TB2.Text = num1
        End If
        Timer1.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        TB1.Text = TB1.Text + 1
        If TB1.Text = 10 Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The `Text` property of a `TextBox` is a `String`. DO NOT treat `Strings` as numbers. If you want to work with numbers then work with numbers. Declare a variable of type `Integer`, increment that variable and compare that variable to your limit. If you want to display the number, convert it to a `String` and display the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a numeric variable to keep the count, not the TextBox. The TextBox.Text property is of type String, not Integer!

Putting `Option Strict On` at the top of your code will enforce using proper types. VB by default allows you to loosely convert between integer and string, which is poor practice.

```vb
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

    Private count As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        count = 0
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If count = 10 Then
            Dim randomnumber As New Random()
            Dim num1 = randomnumber.Next(100, 201)
            TB2.Text = num1.ToString()
        End If
        Timer1.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        count += 1
        Timer1.Enabled = count <> 10
        TB1.Text = count.ToString()
    End Sub

End Class
```

[image]